# Service Broker Message Statistics

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Are there any ways using the data already stored by Service Broker to form statistics such as Average Message Lifetime or Average Message Processing Time for a specific queue? I'm not finding any date/time information on any of the Service Broker tables that I know of. Conversations/Dialogs can have an expiration lifetime so there must be some of this information somewhere. The most helpful information would be if there is a message add/created and errored/completed timestamps available without insertions into custom tables.

Answer (score 1):

Recent variants(post 2012?) of [`sys.transmission_queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190336.aspx) expose `enqueue_time` for debugging. But there is no end-to-end timing info (time created, time in target, time to process etc). Anything you build would have to be based on adding metadata to the message itself, in the application payload, and tracking it in your own tables.

Comment: That's exactly as I anticipated but thank you for confirming.